# Button region Win32Api

Tags: winapi

I create a `PUSHBUTTON` with this code:

```
hWndBtn = CreateWindow(L"Button", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, x, y, width, height, hWndParent, (HMENU)IDC_MYBUTTON, hInst, NULL);
```

Then, I create a Ellipse region:

```
HRGN hRgn = CreateEllipticRgn(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

Finally I set button region:

```
SetWindowRgn(hWndBtn, hRgn, true);
```

But my button is still rectangle. How can I make it an ellipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SetWindowRgn` only works on top-level windows, not child windows.